# .Scam issue ApprovalForAll(send nft from owner to another wallet)

Tags: nft, smart-contract-wallets, scam

this guy use the following code to scam and send nft via smart contract between my wallet to his wallet

.ApprovalForAll( owner=[Sender] 0x8642b756a009d29da93dec774aa8bc5a329abae1, operator=0xE42E42EB06266D2Fab1B8E539792Efe26A4C3C2d, approved=True )

https://etherscan.io/tx-decoder?tx=0x5ab6f282f9f314b698c9b5741d853ebd066b9d19fd033b081aa1879d0a934d2e

and I let my wallet connected to smart contract tell now, is there any way to send it back from his wallet?

https://etherscan.io/tx/0x656cc2192566986924ffba30b7104fc679a19601216bbb11dfb1c6c006c56506#eventlog